How can I protect an unprotected hot tub outlet?
I just bought a house & didn't realize/notice through walk-through until today this unsafe situation/setup where receptacle (even though it is a GFCI) which the jacuzzi is plugged into is right next to jacuzzi...planning (DIY) to change it. I have considered two options:

Install a new GFCI receptacle 3' above the jacuzzi rim & blank-out the current receptacle.

Make jacuzzi hard-wired & replace the current non-GFCI breaker in the panel with a GFCI.


I would rather do the 2nd option so not to bother with cutting out a hole in the wall, etc. etc. in order to make a new GFCI receptacle. Comments please?

If you can get cabling from the panel to underneath the tub without breaking any walls do that.  It doesn't matter if it's hard wired or if you put a receptacle under there.  Either way it will be GF protected from the panel and protected from splashing by the tub.
Otherwise you can replace the breaker with a GFCI one anyway and put a locked outdoor cover on this outlet.  Ugly but achieves the same thing and not more ugly than a 3 foot cable up the wall.
The big danger as-is is copious water splashing into the live wires behind the outlet without GF protection.  Moving the GFCI device to the panel protects all the wiring in the vicinity of the tub, and protecting it from splashing or being handled from inside the tub adds another layer of safety.   Not sure if a locked waterproof cover will achieve code compliance but it will achieve the goal.
